# Java permutations causes heap space error

Tags: java, algorithm, exception, permutation, heap-memory

I have a program which generates permutations of number combinations. The permutations have a given size (in this case 6). My problem is that I get a **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error** with bigger number combinations. For example, if I calculate permuations out of 18 numbers I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at javax.swing.text.GapContent.allocateArray(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.GapVector.resize(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.GapVector.shiftEnd(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.GapContent.shiftEnd(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.GapVector.open(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.GapVector.replace(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.GapContent.insertString(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTextArea.append(Unknown Source)
at test.permute(test.java:48)
at test.permute(test.java:52)
at test.permute(test.java:52)
at test.permute(test.java:52)
at test.permute(test.java:52)
at test.permute(test.java:52)
at test.permute(test.java:52)
at test.actionPerformed(test.java:74)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
```

Now it seems like this is caused by printing out the permutations in the JTextArea because you can see the error at javax.swing.text if you look at the first lines of the exception.

Here is the code I use:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton ok;
    private JTextArea text;
    private String str;
    private JScrollPane scroll;

    public test() { 
        panel = new JPanel();
        ok = new JButton("OK");
        ok.addActionListener(this);
        str = ("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, ");
        text = new JTextArea(str, 16, 16);
        text.setEditable(true); 
        scroll = new JScrollPane(text);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);


        panel.add(scroll);
        panel.add(ok);
        add(panel); 

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test();
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void permute(java.util.List<Integer> intList, int k, int max) {
          if(k == max) {
            text.append(Arrays.toString(intList.subList(0, max).toArray()).replaceAll( "\\[|\\]", "") + ", \n");
          } else {
            for(int i = k; i < intList.size(); i++){
              java.util.Collections.swap(intList, i, k);
              permute(intList, k+1, max);
              java.util.Collections.swap(intList, k, i);
            }
          }
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String a = text.getText();  
        text.setText("");

        String[] zahlenstring = a.split(", ");
        int[] zahlenint = new int[zahlenstring.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < zahlenstring.length ;i++) {
            zahlenint[i] = Integer.parseInt(zahlenstring[i]); }

        ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < zahlenint.length; i++) {
            intList.add(zahlenint[i]); }

        permute(intList, 0, 6);    
    }
}
```

I looked for solutions but I mainly found advices for adding ram to java or to use multithreading, which both I dont want to use here.

Now my question is: How can I improve this code, so that it doesnt give me that exeption anymore? Is here even anything to improve?

You can ask in the comments if you still have questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: how many permutations of 18 numbers are there? How much RAM do you have?

Comment: You can ask for the *impossible*, but don't expect a useful answer. 18! is a pretty big number.

Comment: @nneonneo I have a Notebook with 8 GB RAM, but the program is needed for a Notebook with only 4 GB RAM.

Comment: Your code fails at `text.append`, so there isn't much possibility to do anything differently...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building up a String which uses a very large (or impractical) amount of memory you need to process each permutation as it is determined.

```
public static void permute(List<Integer> intList,  Consumer<List<Integer>> permutationConsumer) {
    permute(intList, 0, intList.size(), permutationConsumer);
}

public static void permute(List<Integer> intList, int k, int max, Consumer<List<Integer>> permutationConsumer) {
   if(k == max) {
        permutationConsumer.accept(intList.subList(0, max));
        return;
   }
   for(int i = k; i < intList.size(); i++) {
        Collections.swap(intList, i, k);
        permute(intList, k + 1, max, permutationConsumer);
        Collections.swap(intList, k, i);
   }
}
```

This solution will not use any more memory.

To display this results as you go you can do

```
permute(intList, System.out::println);
```

This doesn't build up a large string before display it, so you won't run out of memory.

Comment: Im not familiar with Lambda, but this code just stores every permutation in the list `permutationConsumer`, right?. So I have to output all permutations later anyway to display them, which would bild up a big String again or did I understand something wrong here?

Comment: @OlafStein You don't have to use a lambda.  What this does is allow to to process the data as you receive it.  This is your only options as you don't have enough space to build up a big String. BTW Strings cannot hold more the 2 billion characters no matter how much memory you have.

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with large numbers of elements it is good idea to calculate in advance how many memory they will consume.

Your permutations will consume [image: permutations[1]] bytes, presuming each combination consumes 12 bytes. So the total amount of consumed memory will be around 160MB. This amount of memory is required only to store the combinations as strings. When you are adding them to TextArea, you are at least doubling the amount of required memory.

The easiest way to solve your memory issues is to output you permutation as soon as it is computed. You can write it to console or to file. In this case you will not require any additional memory.

However, if your only option is to create GUI application, then you can do the following. At first, you need to realize that you need at least (13366080 * k) bytes to for permutations strings (where k is the size of each permutation as string), 13366080 * 16 bytes for storing the array of strings and some extra memory to make application run smoothly (prevent GC pauses). If my calculations are correct, it will be something around 500Mb of heap memory.

Next, you should not add your strings directly to TextArea. Instead, create `ArrayList<String>` of your permutations, create ScrollBar, initialize it with the size of your results array. On position change of the ScrollBar reinitialize TextArea with the elements at the position of ScrollBar (take some small number of elements from the position of scroll bar and add them to TextArea as lines).